# Why are only two lines showing up on my canvas?

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas

I have arrays of points for lines to be drawn to my canvas element, however, only two lines are being drawn to the canvas.  When I do a console log on each array, the correct array actually prints out.  Can anyone tell me why they're not all showing up though?

**JS**

```
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i = 0; i < result[0].back_lines.x1.length - 1; i++){
    ctx.moveTo(result[0].back_lines.x1[i], result[0].back_lines.y1[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(result[0].back_lines.x2[i], result[0].back_lines.y2[i]);
}
ctx.lineWidth = result[0].back_lines.width;
ctx.strokeStyle = result[0].back_lines.stroke;
ctx.stroke();
```

**JSON**

```
[{
    "back_lines": {
        "width": 6,
        "stroke": "#000000",
        "x1": [938.4, 621.283, 621.283, 604.267, 549.1, 504.233, 582.817, 582.817, 380.033, 477.5, 477.5, 379.42, 379.42, 344.73, 344.73, 588.37, 646.6, 646.6, 804.33, 804.33, 601.05, 601.05, 597.433, 597.433, 475.433, 362.467, 208.8, 191.217, 191.217, 645.017, 645.017, 866.617, 866.617, 849.25, 849.25, 849.25, 360.033, 360.033, 360.033, 209.8, 209.8, 566.5, 566.5, 611, 611, 360.033, 478.05, 793.083, 793.083, 576, 793.083, 843.32, 843.32, 478.05, 504.233, 504.233, 587.37, 646.07, 646.07, 804.43, 803.4, 622.52, 622.52],
        "y1": [258.167, 177.82, 177.82, 258.167, 257.633, 256.633, 257.9, 214.22, 214.22, 366, 484.133, 269.767, 308.82, 308.82, 557.05, 483.5, 483.5, 515, 515, 499.2, 483, 434.3, 141.667, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 586.083, 586.083, 534.783, 534.783, 515.417, 499.2, 499.2, 409.683, 111.267, 111.267, 84.383, 84.383, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 498.667, 84.383, 84.383, 84.383, 377.233, 377.233, 84.383, 84.383, 120.5, 84.383, 366, 466.15, 467.27, 467.27, 394.52, 394.52, 409.7, 467.8, 403.42],
        "x2": [868, 621.283, 621.283, 604.267, 549.1, 504.233, 582.817, 582.817, 380.033, 477.5, 477.5, 379.42, 379.42, 344.73, 344.73, 588.37, 646.6, 646.6, 804.33, 804.33, 601.05, 601.05, 597.433, 597.433, 475.433, 362.467, 208.8, 191.217, 191.217, 645.017, 645.017, 866.617, 866.617, 849.25, 849.25, 849.25, 360.033, 360.033, 360.033, 209.8, 209.8, 566.5, 566.5, 611, 611, 360.033, 478.05, 793.083, 793.083, 576, 793.083, 843.32, 843.32, 478.05, 504.233, 504.233, 587.37, 646.07, 646.07, 804.43, 803.4, 622.52,  622.52],
        "y2": [258.167, 225.45, 225.45, 258.167, 257.633, 256.633, 257.9, 214.22, 214.22, 366, 484.133, 269.767, 308.82, 308.82, 557.05, 483.5, 483.5, 515, 515, 499.2, 483, 434.3, 141.667, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 586.083, 586.083, 534.783, 534.783, 515.417, 499.2, 499.2, 409.683, 111.267, 111.267, 84.383, 84.383, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 498.667, 84.383, 84.383, 84.383, 377.233, 377.233, 84.383, 84.383, 120.5, 84.383, 366, 466.15, 467.27, 467.27, 394.52, 394.52, 409.7, 467.8, 403.42]
    }
}]
```

Comment: It looks like in most entries x1==x2 and y1==y2.

Comment: @georg, yes, that is the case, some lines start where other lines end or vice versa, but that shouldn't be why there are only two showing up on the canvas.  In other words, there are no lines that sit on top of each other.

Comment: @Robert What georg means is that if you have a line whose starting and ending point are the same, it's not a line. It's a point.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, then no that's not the case, there are no lines that have the same starting and ending point.

Comment: @Robert Au contraire, _all_ of your lines have the same starting and ending point except the first three.

Comment: Well crap, they do.  I must've missed that.  Thanks for pointing that out guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that almost all of your x1/x2 and y1/y2 pairs have the same value, except for the first three pairs. That means that they won't form a line.

Perhaps a starting or ending point got added or deleted somewhere?

Additionally, I would suggest using DRYer code and assigning your object to a variable instead of repeating the same array index/property accesses, and you had an off-by-one error in your `for` loop:

```
var backLines = result[0].back_lines,
    x1 = backLines.x1,
    y1 = backLines.y1,
    x2 = backLines.x2,
    y2 = backLines.y2;

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.lineWidth = backLines.width;
ctx.strokeStyle = backLines.stroke;
for(var i = 0; i < x1.length; i++){
    ctx.moveTo(x1[i], y1[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(x2[i], y2[i]);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Will do.  Thanks.  I think I was simply using the wrong lines as my points and didn't notice what I was doing.